# altering an existing xml prolog with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I've seen questions/answers for Java and C#, but none for JavaScript.

If I have an XML doc/string with a standard prolog, how would it be accessed?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`

As the prolog does not in and of itself have an element name, it cannot, to my knowledge, be targetted by `xml.getElementByTagName()`, therefore making it impossible to remove any attribute of the prolog.

For example, if I had some XML that looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <element>text</element>
</root>
```

I would be able to target `<element>` and add attributes, remove text, etc. But, let's say I wanted to alter or remove the standalone declaration. I wouldn't be able to target it with normal methods.

So, how can the prolog be altered programatically using JavaScript?

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to improve yours.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I made some additions. Does that work?

Comment: Yeah, looks better.

Answer (score 3):

This worked from Firefox dev tools console:

```js
// build an xml
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "books");
// print XML string
(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
```

Just root node

```
"<books/>"
```

Now create a doc with your requirement

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
prolog = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>';
// Add existing XML starting at root element
newXmlStr = prolog + (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
var xml  = parser.parseFromString(newXmlStr, "application/xml");
// print raw xml
console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml));
```

New XML string:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<books/>"
```

Other cases:

`prolog = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';`

`prolog = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>';`

If your xml already contains a prolog, get it starting at root element with `xml.documentElement`

```js
prolog = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
XmlStr = prolog + "<bookz/>";
var xmlz  = parser.parseFromString(XmlStr, "application/xml");
console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlz));
```

XML with `standalone="yes"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bookz/>
```

New XML:

```js
// set standalone="no"
prolog = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>';
// serialize existing xml at root node
newXmlStr = prolog + (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlz.documentElement);
// Rebuild with new prolog
var xml  = parser.parseFromString(newXmlStr, "application/xml");
```

XML with `standalone="no"`

```
console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml));
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<bookz/>
```

Comment: What if the XML document whose prolog you're trying to alter already has a prolog and doesn't start at the root element, limiting the possibility of concatenating a new prolog?

Comment: Added example for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to simply strip the unfavorable prolog and replace it with the favorable prolog using `str.replace()`.

If the unfavorable prolog is as follows:

```
var badProlog = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'
```

And the favorable prolog is as follows:

```
var goodProlog = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
```

Use the following method to replace the prolog:

```
xmlStr.replace(badProlog, goodProlog)
```